# Replace certain words in a sentence

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app in Android Studio that translates certain words that I've made up myself. I've got the part in the code that translates the words right, but it only works when I type in the word but not when I type the word in a sentence. When I type in the sentence, it does not display anything when I press the button. For example: When I type in "Cookie", I get "Biscuit". But when I type in "I love me a Cookie", it does not display the sentence and the word when I press the button.

This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mType;
    Button mSearch;
    TextView mResults;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeWordTxt);
        mSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.find8tn);
        mResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultsTxt);
        mSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mType.getText().toString().trim().equals("cookie"))
                {
                    mResults.setText("biscuit");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if (mType.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("cookie")) {
    mResults.setText(mType.getText().toString().replaceAll("(?i)cookie", "biscuit"));
}
```

As @Andreas said to the comment below you can use it to replace if is a whole word and not to replace a string in a word.

Comment: Maybe add `\\b`, as in `"(?i)\\bcookie\\b"`?

Comment: Yes a word boundary to define only if is a single word.

Comment: It shows cannot resolve .toLowerCase and .replaceAll. I have beginner Java skills, so i'm still learning. I might not see problems that are obvious. Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: It works guys! Thanks for the help, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple task you can do the below

```
String str = "abc";
str.replace("abc", "xyz");
```

It will replace the word **abc** with **xyz** in the whole string.
Try it an d let me know that is this what you want

Comment: I have tried it and i get the same result that i get with my own code. It can be that i have not implemented your code the right way. I have beginner Java skills and i'm still learning, so i might not see obvious problems. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

Because you use equals, for finding  word from sentence you must use method `contains()` and `replaceAll()` for replace all of this words

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mType.getText().toString().trim().replaceAll("cookie", "biscuit").contains("cookie"))
                {
                    mResults.setText("biscuit");
                }
            }